# How to convert dataframe containing lists to 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to convert the following dataframe to 3-D array of shape (4,200,3)?

```
    df:
          0                     1                  2
    0  [1,2,3.......200]     [4,5,6....200]        [7,8,9....200]
    1  [11,12,13....200]     [14,15,16....200]     [17,18,19....200]
    2  [21,22,23....200]     [24,25,26....200]     [27,28,29....200]
    3  [31,32,33....200]     [24,25,26....200]     [27,28,29....200]
```

I convert 'df' using np.array(df).
It is giving an array of size(4,3) which is 2-D.

How to convert into 3-D array of size (4,200,3)?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the result for me, the shape you want the data and also you're code?

A hypothesis of it giving you a `size(4,3)` is probably because you have a `panda file with 4 rows and 3 columns` and when you convert the data into `NumPy`, the data within example `df[0,0]` -> `list([1,2,3,...,200])`

If you're actual data is `(4,3)`, then that means it is 'impossible' to change a `(4,3)` that has `4x3=12 indices` into a `(4,200,3)` that has `200x3x4=2400 indices`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.  Issue resolved. I converted entire dataframe to list again convert that list to 3D array using numpy.      df_list = df.values.tolist(), df_array = np.array(df_list).